# how to check if quotient is an integer value? python

Tags: python, input, division

Write a Python function to check whether a number is divisible by another number.
Accept two integers values form the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo operator for that `%` and check whether it returns 0 or not.

```
def divisible(m, n):
    return m % n == 0

print(divisible(30, 6))
print(divisible(23, 5))
```

Result

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a built-in operator for this [modulo (`%`)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations). You can use it to get the rest of the division of two numbers. You can also use a trick to get a boolean value when two numbers are divisible without a remainder by checking the result with a logical 'not' in front of it. In Python, boolean values are actually the numbers 0 and 1, so the truth value only needs to be inverted for the correct result.

```py
def check_divisibility(m, n):
    return not m % n
```